# How can I parse, sort, and print a 90MB JSON file with 100,000 records to CSV?

Tags: php, json, performance, sorting, memory

## Background

I'm trying to complete a code challenge where I need to refactor a simple PHP application that accepts a JSON file of people, sorts them by registration date, and outputs them to a CSV file. The provided program is **already functioning** and works fine with a small input but **intentionally fails with a large input**. In order to complete the challenge, the program should be modified to be able to parse and sort a 100,000 record, 90MB file without running out of memory, like it does now.

In it's current state, the program uses `file_get_contents()`, followed by `json_decode()`, and then `usort()` to sort the items. This works fine with the *small* sample data file, however not with the *large* sample data file - it runs out of memory.

### The input file

The file is in JSON format and contains 100,000 objects. Each object has a `registered` attribute (example value `2017-12-25 04:55:33`) and this is how the records in the CSV file should be sorted, in ascending order.

## My attempted solution

Currently, I've used the `halaxa/json-machine` package, and I'm able to iterate over each object in the file. For example

```
$people = \JsonMachine\JsonMachine::fromFile($fileName);
foreach ($people as $person) {
    // do something
}
```

Reading the whole file into memory as a PHP array is not an option, as it takes up too much memory, so the only solution I've been able to come up with so far has been iterating over each object in the file, finding the person with the earliest registration date and printing that. Then, iterating over the whole file again, finding the next person with the earliest registration date and printing that etc.

The **big** issue with that is that the nested loops: a loop which runs 100,000 times containing a loop that runs 100,000 times. It's not a viable solution, and that's the furthest I've made it.

**How can I parse, sort, and print to CSV, a JSON file with 100,000 records? Usage of packages / services is allowed.**

Comment: I mean.. the whole point of a challenge is to do it yourself.. why are you even doing it, if you're asking for an answer from someone else?

Comment: I show example ,what do you  want ? Json write as CSV ?

Comment: @CrayonViolent because... I can't figure out how to do it? And rather than just give up I'd like to expand my knowledge

Comment: maybe someting [like this json stream parser](https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser) could help.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I'm using a different, similar package but how can I use it to sort through the items? Because each object needs to be sorted according to a `registered` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up importing into MongoDB in chunks and then retrieving in the correct order to print

Example import:

```php
$collection = (new Client($uri))->collection->people;
$collection->drop();

$people = JsonMachine::fromFile($fileName);

$chunk = [];
$chunkSize = 5000;
$personNumber = 0;
foreach ($people as $person) {
    $personNumber += 1;
    $chunk[] = $person;
    if ($personNumber % $chunkSize == 0) { // Chunk is full
        $this->collection->insertMany($chunk);
        $chunk = [];
    }
}
// The very last chunk was not filled to the max, but we still need to import it
if(count($chunk)) {
    $this->collection->insertMany($chunk);
}
// Create an index for quicker sorting
$this->collection->createIndex([ 'registered' => 1 ]);
```

Example retrieve:

```php
$results = $this->collection->find([],
    [
        'sort' => ['registered' => 1],
    ]
);

// For every person...
foreach ($results as $person) {
    // For every attribute...
    foreach ($person as $key => $value) {
        if($key != '_id') { // No need to include the new MongoDB ID
            echo some_csv_encode_function($value) . ',';
        }
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```